# CSS - Hide the Text

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I want to hide the text..

```
<div id: "hideen_text"
    <a href="http://localhost:3000/photos/12.html">
      <img src="https:0f25438da28b758ea0a65d69c188e505.jpg" width="2500" height="1685">
      1758345.jpg (I WANT TO HIDE THIS ONE)
    </a>
</div>
```

Any Clue for this? THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiding the complete div would be:

```
<div style="display: none">
```

Hiding just the text in the div would be this:

```
<div>
   <a href="http://localhost:3000/photos/12.html">
      <img src="https:0f25438da28b758ea0a65d69c188e505.jpg" width="2500" height="1685">
      <div style="display:none">1758345.jpg</div>
   </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, use:

> #hideen_text {
> display: none;
> }